# How to use native contact app to update contact in ios?

Tags: ios, contacts

I'm showing all of the contacts fetched from the address book, now what I want is a way to redirect user to the native contact app for editing a contact and return back to the app when user is done updating contact.

I can update the contact within the app, but I want to use the native app, please help me if there's any way to do achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Why? Why not use the standard UI controls provided by the ContactsUI framework to allow the user to update a contact without the need to leave your app?

Comment: @rmaddy will that use the native contact app?

Comment: No. That's my question. Why do you want to force the user to switch to the native Contacts app when there is no reason to do so.

Comment: For privacy reason, like user doesn't feel that his contacts are being edited inside the app.